# Using Proxy Protocol with AWS ELBs and IIS 8

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis-8

I'm trying to move my SignalR application, hosted in AWS behind an ELB on IIS8, to use websockets.

After following the steps recommended by AWS (change listeners on the ELB to TCP, enable proxy protocol - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html) I'm unable to find a way of getting IIS to understand the proxy protocol information, and get bad requests instead.

Has anyone been successful in getting websockets through an AWS ELB and IIS working?

Comment: Did you ever find anything? We're running into the same issue and can't seem to find anything to make IIS recognize the proxy protocol.

Comment: For anyone wanting to still do this, it seems like the new Application Load Balancer supports websockets - https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/

Answer (score 1):

IIS currently does not support Proxy Protocol. With AWS do as Dave suggests, and take a look at using ALB, as this has Web Socket support, so before the connection upgrades you will have X-Forwarded-For headers.